# Upgrading from Cordova < 4: Current alternative for CordovaXXClients

Tags: android, cordova, webview, apache-cordova

I'm upgrading some legacy Cordova 2.x and 3.x apps to version 5.1.0. In the old projects the WebView was customized using the now gone `CordovaChromeClient` and `CordovaWebViewClient` classes.

Is there a replacement for these classes in the new API?

In particular, I'd like to:

- Set a higher database quota for SQLite. 
  This was done in the old times calling `WebView.setWebChromeClient` and passing as parameter an instance of `CordovaChromeClient` with its `onExceededDatabaseQuota` method overridden.
- Override URL loading.
  This was done in Cordova 3.x and lower calling `WebView.setWebViewClient` and passing as parameter an instance of `CordovaWebViewClient` with its `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old `CordovaWebViewClient` is now the `SystemWebViewClient`

The old `CordovaChromeClient` is now the `SystemWebChromeClient`

To get the `SystemWebView` use the getView and cast it

```
((SystemWebView)appView.getView())
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if theres a way to obtain a `SystemWebViewEngine` from inside a `CordovaActivity`? I need one to pass it to the clients constructors.

Comment: edited with information about how to get the `SystemWebView` (that's what you need, not the `SystemWebViewEngine`)

Comment: Actually I'm sure I need the engine. But I'll use shameless casting as well. I don't think there's another way.

Comment: `SystemWebView` is the one with `setWebChromeClient` and `setWebViewClient` as it extends `WebView`, `SystemWebViewEngine` has a Client, but you can't set it